# why did Joshua Bloch decrement the "size" value of stack in the pop method in effective java?

Tags: java, stack, effective-java

here is the code from Item 6, pg 24, chapter 2 of effective java 2nd edition, by Joshua Bloch.
In the pop method he defines, he uses `elements[--size]`. I am wondering why he used `--size`, instead `elements[size--]` should return the same correct?

```
public class Stack {
       private Object[] elements;
       private int size = 0;
       private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
       public Stack() {
           elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
}
       public void push(Object e) {
           ensureCapacity();
           elements[size++] = e;
}
       public Object pop() {
           if (size == 0)
               throw new EmptyStackException();
           return elements[--size];
}
       /**
        * Ensure space for at least one more element, roughly
        * doubling the capacity each time the array needs to grow.
        */
       private void ensureCapacity() {
           if (elements.length == size)
               elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
} }
```

Comment: Arrays uses 0-based indices.

Comment: looks like there's a memory leak - the popped element is still referenced by stack.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu: yes, the memory leak could be fixed by referencing the `elements[size]==null`

Comment: The reverse of `size++` is `--size`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hadn't really thought about it like that, that's interesting. Incrementing after evaluation, is completely complimentary to decrementing before evaluation

Comment: @Cruncher similar is a write barrier after a write and a read barrier before a read.

Comment: @brainstorm I think it'd need to be `Object o = elements[--size]; elements[size] = null; return o;`

Comment: For those pointing out the memory leak: Although brain storm doesn't mention it, Joshua Bloch's full title for this section is "Item 6: Eliminate obsolete object references", and the first paragraph following the example is "There is nothing obviously wrong with this program [...] it would pass every test with flying colors, but there's a problem lurking.  Loosely speaking, the program has a 'memory leak', [...]".  It's intentional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because arrays are 0 based indexed.

Imagine that you have a stack with 2 elements.

So the size of the stack is equals to 2 with the following representation in the array :

```
elements[0] = elem;
elements[1] = elem;
```

So you need to decrease size before pop the elem from the stack, otherwise you will try to pop `elements[2]`, which doesn't exists. So an infix operator is used in this case.

```
return elements[--size];
```

is equivalent to

```
size--;
return elements[size];
```

If `elements[size--];` was written, it would try to pop `elements[2]` and then decrease size by 1. So an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown each time you want to pop an element from the stack.

Comment: @ZouZou this is almost perfect. "So an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown each time you want to pop an element from the stack." This is not entirely correct. Assuming the exception is caught and handled the first time, the next time around the size decrement will be there, and it will work from here, but throw an empty stack exception when there is still 1 element left.

Comment: @Cruncher Thanks for the precisions ! =) I assumed that the exception is not caught and the execution of the program will be stopped.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is the minus-minus (or plus plus) acts before iterating when it comes before the variable and after iterating when it comes after the variable.

For example:

```
for(x=0; x<3; x++) {
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

returns:

```
012
```

While:

```
for(x=0; x<3; ++x) {
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

returns:

```
123
```

because the x variable is incremented before the iteration.

Comment: This question has no iteration. The point is that ++x increments before EVALUATION, and x++ increments AFTER evaluation.

Comment: This is totally false. Did you try your code before ? Both give 012.